# XSL 1.0 unique values from variable

Tags: xslt

I am not familiar with XSL and I am writing a code which has a variable:

```
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(contains(normalize-space(@State.),$State) or string-length($State) = 0) and (contains(normalize-space(@Event_x0020_Display_x0),$Month) or string-length($Month) = 0) and (contains(normalize-space(@Event_x0020_Type),$EventType) or string-length($EventType) = 0)]"/>
```

I need to use this variable to populate 3 dropdownlist with unique values.
I have tried several thing and the code below would work if the page is load with all values. however if I filter using a parameter the values in the dropdown gets mess up.

```
<td class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">
<select name="Select1" style="width:200px;">
   <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
    <xsl:sort select="@State"/>
     <xsl:if test="not(@State=preceding-sibling::Row/@State)">
        <option>
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@State,'#')" />
       </option>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</select>
</td>
```

Comment: Just one more thing. It seems that it is always missing one unique value. Usually the last one. I've tried adding to the if statement  "or Position() = Last()" but them in the other dropdownlist the last value is duplicated.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, unique values are derived using Muenchian grouping - see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and many, many examples here on SO. Alternatively, if your processor supports it, you could use the [EXSLT set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function.